# How to locally test a dockerized app connected with AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

Sorry Docker starter question here.

I'm currently trying to build an app with Python using FastApi and dockerize it. When it's dockerized I will connect it to an AWS Lambda. The problem is, how can I test my Lambda before deploying it to ECR?

I already tried to use the local Lambda invoke with: localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations and create a post request reading a file:

```json
{   
"resource": "/",   
"path": "/upload/",   
"httpMethod": "POST",   
"requestContext": {},   
"multiValueQueryStringParameters": null,   
"headers": {     
  "Accept": "application/json",     
  "Content-Type": "application/json"   },   
  "body": {     "filename": "image.jpg" },   
  "files": {     "upload": "image.jpg" } 
}
```

I don't get it to work...

Code:

```py
@app.post("/upload/")
async def upload_image(request: Request):
  print(request)
  print(await request.json())
  print(await request.body())
  
  return {"received_request_body": request.json()}


handler = Mangum(app)
```

Comment: What issue are you seeing?

Comment: I have a lambda function which contains 3gb of libraries (Machine learning related). I can't put that in the lambda so I use a lambda container and connect is to a lambda function. But how can I test this locally without deploying the docker instance to ECR? Or is this not possible. Because every time I change something in the lambda I need to deploy the code to de docker image and deploy it again to ECR right?

Answer (score 0):

Does your container image include the runtime interface emulator (RIE)? Did you build and run the container image? Take a read through the following reference:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html

You might also check out AWS SAM CLI, which offers a nice workflow for local build and test of Lambda functions.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-build.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your complete infra.But based on the above given limited information I am trying to answer.
You can test lambda independently with test events.You can do this from either AWS console or from cli (aws lambda invoke).

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/testing-functions.html

But if you want to test it with api then use api gateway along with your lambda which will expose it as an endpoint.Then you can test your lambda which ever way you are comfortable(like curl command/postman etc..)

Reference
[Api Gateway with lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html)

[Navigation for test event from Lambda console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK64l.png)

[Test event for Lambda screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4pZj.png)